# MediaWiki API not returning depictions in languages other than English

Tags: mediawiki-api, wikimedia, wikimedia-commons, wikibase

I was using the API https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbsearchentities to fetch depictions In Wikimedia Commons.

On modifying the attributes language/strictlanguage should return depiction in the corresponding language

I found that none of the calls

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&format=json&language=hi&search=Q528943
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&format=json&language=hi&strictlanguage=1&search=Q528943

... returns depiction in the desired language.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the entity ID, there is no point in searching, you can just use `wbgetentities`:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=wbgetentities&ids=Q528943&props=labels|aliases|descriptions&languages=hi

```
{
    "entities": {
        "Q528943": {
            "type": "item",
            "id": "Q528943",
            "labels": {
                "hi": {
                    "language": "hi",
                    "value": "\u0917\u0941\u0906\u0928 \u092c\u094d\u0932\u094b\u092b\u094b\u0930\u094d\u0921"
                }
            },
            "descriptions": {
                "hi": {
                    "language": "hi",
                    "value": "\u0905\u092e\u0947\u0930\u093f\u0915\u0940 \u0905\u0902\u0924\u0930\u093f\u0915\u094d\u0937 \u092f\u093e\u0924\u094d\u0930\u0940"
                }
            },
            "aliases": {}
        }
    },
    "success": 1
}
```

For `wbsearchentities`, you'd have to use `uselang` as opposed to `language` (which sets the language to search descriptions in, not to display descriptions in... this is very unintuitive, but sort of mentioned in the API description).